# cocos2d::extension::ScrollView::create() causes unresolved external symbol (VS2012)

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm having difficulties adding a scroll view to a menu using cocos2d-x. I'm using cocos2d::extension::ScrollView::create() to create the scroll, but when compiled, I get error:

Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class cocos2d::extension::ScrollView * __cdecl cocos2d::extension::ScrollView::create(class cocos2d::Size,class cocos2d::Node *)" (?create@ScrollView@extension@cocos2d@@SAPAV123@VSize@3@PAVNode@3@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall ScrollMenuScene::init(void)" (?init@ScrollMenuScene@@UAE_NXZ) C:\Cocos\cocos2d-x-3.0\~\MyCompany\MyGame\proj.win32\ScrollMenuScene.obj    MyGame

Below is a code snippet of the h and cpp files, down to the bear minimum, but include all the necessary code that is causing the build to error out.

The main line that is causing the error is:

```
_scrollView = cocos2d::extension::ScrollView::create(_scrollContainer->getContentSize(), _scrollContainer);
```

If I don't instantiate the _scrollView pointer, it does not error out, so it is specifically happening when I call ScrollView::create

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

*Note in the code below I added the entire file to show the includes, definitions, and implementations, as that is where I usually find unresolved errors.

.h file

```
#ifndef SCROLL_MENU_SCENE_H
#define SCROLL_MENU_SCENE_H

#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "cocos-ext.h"

class ScrollMenuScene : public cocos2d::Layer
{
private:
   cocos2d::Node* _scrollContainer;
   cocos2d::extension::ScrollView *_scrollView;
   cocos2d::Menu* _menu;

public:
   // there's no 'id' in cpp, so we recommend returning the class instance pointer
   static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();

   // Here's a difference. Method 'init' in cocos2d-x returns bool, instead of returning 'id' in cocos2d-iphone
   virtual bool init();

   ~ScrollMenuScene(void);

   // implement the "static create()" method manually
   CREATE_FUNC(ScrollMenuScene);

   //Menu callback.
   void Menu_Handler(cocos2d::Ref* sender);
};

#endif //SCROLL_MENU_SCENE_H
```

.cpp file

```
#include "ScrollMenuScene.h"

cocos2d::Scene* ScrollMenuScene::createScene()
{
   // 'scene' is an autorelease object
   auto scene = cocos2d::Scene::create();

   // 'layer' is an autorelease object
   auto layer = ScrollMenuScene::create();

   // add layer as a child to scene
   scene->addChild(layer);

   // return the scene
   return scene;
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
bool ScrollMenuScene::init()
{
   //Call base first.
   if (!Layer::init())
   {
      return false;
   }

   cocos2d::Point worldCenter = cocos2d::Point(this->getContentSize() / 2);

   _scrollContainer = cocos2d::Node::create();
   _scrollContainer->setPosition(worldCenter);
   _scrollContainer->setContentSize(this->getContentSize() / 2); //half the size of the layer.

   _scrollView = cocos2d::extension::ScrollView::create(_scrollContainer->getContentSize(), _scrollContainer);
   _scrollView->setPosition(worldCenter);
   _scrollView->setDirection(cocos2d::extension::ScrollView::Direction::VERTICAL);

   //Add Menu.
   cocos2d::MenuItemImage *item0 = cocos2d::MenuItemImage::create("Images/PlayMenu/PlayMenuTile0.png",
      "Images/PlayMenu/PlayMenuTile0.png", this, menu_selector(ScrollMenuScene::Menu_Handler));

   _menu = cocos2d::Menu::create();
   _menu->addChild(item0);

   _menu->alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding(20);
   _menu->setPosition(worldCenter);
   this->addChild(_menu);

   //add scroll view to layer.
   this->addChild(_scrollView);

   return true;
}

void ScrollMenuScene::Menu_Handler(cocos2d::Ref* sender)
{
   //<Menu item tap implementation>
}

ScrollMenuScene::~ScrollMenuScene()
{
   _scrollContainer->release();
}
```

Comment: add extensions project and library in linker to your project

Comment: @VikasPatidar. I went to Linker/General/Additional Library Directories, added $(EngineRoot)extensions. When compiled, I get the same errors. Then added the project libExtensions.vcxproj to solution, and get 21 errors “cannot open include file: 'thread' No such file or directory” - comes from CCConsole.h @ libExtensions. + still get original 2 errors. What is also odd is that I can access parts of the ScrollView without having to link the project. For example, I can run cocos2d::extension::ScrollView::Direction without errors, and this enum is located inside the same ScrollView file. Any ideas?

Comment: there is template project named `cpp-empty-test` in `tests` directory. You can try it. All the extensions are included there along with header search path and linker libraries.

Comment: @VikasPatidar. Thanks. I'll give it a try over the next couple of days and see how it goes. Hopefully this will also solve the problem I'm having with Android - it won't compile giving me similar issues.

Comment: @VikasPatidar. Using the test project did not work either, and I got the same error messages. But I did find a fix for it. I'll post it under the answer. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed related to what @VikasPatidar suggested. Adding the libExtensions project to my solution solved part of the problem.

The next problem that arose was a series of missing references to include files Mutex and Thread. Those files are part of C++ and are included in VS2012. The problem was that they were not part of the External Dependencies in the libExtensions project and could not figure out how to add them.

To solve that problem I opened the cocos2d-win32.vc2012.sln under my game's folder/cocos2d/build. When I did this, VS found that it was out of sync and ask me to sync. After it synced, all external dependencies were mapped correctly. Note that I did this in my game's folder, not the Cocos/cocos2d-x-3.0 folder.

I personally think this was caused because the original download I got from cocos was not compatible with vs2012, but vs2010 instead, because the libExtensions project was getting loaded with a vs2010 flag.

To summarize,

1. Add the cocos2d/extensions/proj.win32/libExtensions.vcxproj project
   to your existing solution.
2. Make sure it is compatible with VS2012. To sync it, just open the build/cocos2d-win32.vc2012.sln in your game and follow the prompts to sync.

Note this is specific to VS. Eclipse and Android may be another problem all together.